# How does the benchmarking code add_benchmarks! work on the runtime?

Tags: benchmarking, macro

I am trying to understand the `runtime-benchmarks` gated code on the `runtime/src/lib.rs` and I realize that we need to "list" and "add" benchmarks that we want to perform : https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_benchmarking/v1/macro.add_benchmark.html

However I just want to make sure my understanding is correct:

1. Unless we add it like so in this code :

```rs
add_benchmarks!(params, batches);
add_benchmark!(params, batches, frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>);
```

it's benchmark won't be found or run when trying to run using `benchmark` subcommand right?

2. Why is `add_benchmarks!(params, batches);` needed? It seems to me the odd one out as all other `add_benchmarks!` usually list a pallet and it's alias beside it.

Comment: never needed to modify any code in runtime/lib.rs, just needed to compile with runtime-benchmarks feature (as long as you dont forget to include the module of benchmarks with a feature in the pallet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's benchmark won't be found or run when trying to run using benchmark subcommand right?

Yes, but that modification should not be needed. Adding you pallet here to the [`define_benchmarks`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e1c033ebe15e6de5ee6a5a81eab2dd213f09d574/cumulus/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L555) should automatically include it in `list_benchmarks` and `add_benchmarks`.

There can be some edge-cases where a custom config impl is needed, but it also does not need to modify either of the two macros ([example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e1c033ebe15e6de5ee6a5a81eab2dd213f09d574/cumulus/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L763)).